# subring isomorphic to the ring and surjection

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f : A  \to B$ be a homomorphism of unital commutative artinian rings.

If $f^{-1}(B)$ is isomorphic to $A$, is $f$ surjective ?

Comment: *If* you write $\,f^{-1}(B)\,$ then you're assuming every element in $\,B\,$ has an inverse image, ergo $\,f\,$ is trivially onto. Perhaps you meant $\,f^{-1}(f(A))\,$ ?...

Comment: @DonAntonio, $f^{-1}(B)$ is defined anyway as $\{ x \in A : f(x) \in B \}$, and it coincides with $A$.

Comment: It may be a matter of convention, @AndreasCaranti : above I meant $$f^{-1}(B):=\{f^{-1}(b)\;;\;b\in B\}$$ but I think it'd be your way, and perhaps more logical, to define $$f^{-1}(B):=\{a\in A\;;\;f(a)\in B\}\,\ldots$$ I shall check this, and in the meantime point taken.

Answer (score 2):

You always have $f^{-1}(B) = A$, but of course there exist non-surjective homomorphisms.